# Mesh transparent until mirror modifier is applied

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, transparency, mirror-modifier

Mesh is transparent in solid preview, as well as in mat preview. It's only like that in edit mode and it disappears once mirror modifier is applied.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

It looks like this, so it's not x-ray mode (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>). How to fix this issue?

Comment: hello could you please share a part of your object where we can see the problem? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Probably hidden vertices in edit mode. ALT H to unhide

Comment: @moonboots  
https://pasteall.org/blend/f53be4f75cad44e3ba94ff8796ae1c0b when you go to the edit mode you can see the problem, I think it has sth to do with materials assignment, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: It works fine for me, it may be a bug, try Alt H as Gorgious says, or try with another Blender version?

Comment: @moonboots I tried, but that's not the problem, it looks like i deleted all the faces ONLY and as in the picture, there are only edges, but once i go to object node it's all alright, I'm gonna go try it on other version, coz I'm currently on 3.1, maybe it has some bugs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it sounds like you’re a noting that the mirror modifier does not actually duplicate the mesh until it’s applied, but it does show you a wire frame of the pseudo-duplicated mash while you’re in edit mode (if the show in edit mode toggle button on the modifier is on) before you apply the modifier. This would be normal behavior.

If the modifier-created side of the car is still wireframe even when you are in object mode, that is a problem.